# How to disable integer assignment (0) to an opaque variable?

Tags: c, opaque-pointers

I have a module whose implementation I want to hide from its clients.

I chose to declare an opaque type which is actually a pointer to structure to be defined only in the implementation.

It all is working fine, except that I can assign the zero value to a variable of this type, which I want to avoid.

Here's an example in C.

header file foo.h

```
/* foo.h */
typedef struct foo *foo_t; /* <- sorry this was obviously flawed, the '*' was missing */


extern void foo_create( foo_t *t );
extern void foo_destroy( foo_t *t );
extern void foo_tile( foo_t x );
```

implementation file foo.c

```
/* foo.c */

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "foo.h"

struct foo {
    int some_member;
};

void foo_create( foo_t *t )
{
    if ( *t==0 ) {
        *t = malloc( sizeof(struct foo) );         
    }
}

void foo_destroy( foo_t *t )
{
    if ( *t!=0 ) {
        free(*t);
        *t    = 0;
    }
}


void foo_tile( foo_t t )
{
    t->some_member++;
}
```

And now here is an example client that uses the module:
bar.c:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main( int argc , char **argv )
{
    foo_t toe;

    foo_create( &toe );
    toe    = 0;  /* <-- How to make the compiler (gcc) refuse this? */
    toe    = 1;  /* <--- the compiler rejects this YAY!!            */
}
```

The opaque type is actually a pointer to a dynamically allocated structure;
If I assign the value 0 to it I incur a memory leak which could be avoided If the compiler denied the assignment of 0 to this opaque pointer.

Assigning non-null values to the pointer isn't accepted by the compiler, so I supose that with a little more effort the same could be achieved for zero value.

Is it possible to disable this assignment? How can I achieve that?
If using some bit of C++ or gcc specific constructs is needed, I'll be ok with that, although a pure C solution would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C++ or C? They're not the same, you probably should pick just one.

Comment: Also 0 is the only integer that can be implicitly converted to any pointer type. You can't stop that if `foo_t` really is a pointer. It's like trying to stop `5` from being assigned to an `int`.

Comment: the huge difference between 0 and 1 is that 0 in this case is 'the null pointer' which is a perfectly valid value for any pointer. Also, since this is tagged C++, why don't use new and delete instead of free and malloc? Then you can take advantage of constructors and destructors.

Comment: And no amount of effort can change that.

Comment: Also I doubt this is really how the code looks, because you `typedef struct foo foo_t;` but then `foo_t toe;` and `toe    = 0;`. That wouldn't be possible because you can't assign `0` to a struct.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie I'm pretty sure it's not the real code.

Comment: This is obviously not c++ code, as that ends up in several compiler errors. Not just for the implicit conversion from <some ptr> to void*, but also because `struct foo x = 0;` is NOT valid c++ code as far as I see (that does work in c??)

Comment: @Voo refer to my previous comment.

Comment: You could use an array type to make your type non-assignable (since arrays aren't lvalues in C), but in order to do that you'll have to provide the full structure definition, which defeats the purpose of having an opaque type.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie : That's correct, I missed the '*' in the typedef :-(. Unfortunately it was in a critical place that changes the meaning of the whole example code. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it that way. The compiler would fail in main():

```
    toe    = 0;  /* <-- How to make the compiler (gcc) refuse this? */
```

It would also fail in foo_destroy():

```
    void foo_destroy( foo_t *t )
    {
        if ( *t!=0 ) {
            free(*t);
            *t    = 0;  /* compiler refuses this also */
        }
    }
```

You might try returning the allocated memory from foo_create() directly rather than passing in the foo_t parameter (emulating a constructor):

```
extern foo_t * foo_create( void );

foo_t * foo_create( void )
{
    foo_t * t;

    t = malloc( sizeof(struct foo) );  

    return(t);       
}

int main( int argc , char **argv )
{
    foo_t * toe;

    toe = foo_create();

    toe = 0; /* Clearly a memory leak via reassignment */
    ...
}
```

Comment: NOTE: What I actually meant in the OP was `typedef struct foo *foo_t`. You made a valid point: If I can disable assignment `toe   = 0;` quite probably I won't be able to perform `*t   = 0;` in the "destructor". I guess I'll have to live with that. Even If I modify the interface to match your suggestion, I still have the same "problem", but at least, the programmer will notice leaks more clearly because what he sees is an explicit pointer.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your typedef is wrong: `typedef struct foo foo_t;` (and so it your `main`, otherwise the compiler will catch the assignments to structures).

For opaque types it is customary to do something like: **`typedef struct foo *foo_t;`**. Otherwise your `toe` wouldn't be a pointer in the example you posted (that's why you had to pass it with &). Considering the `malloc` in `foo_create`, I am pretty sure you typed the wrong typedef.

Second, ask yourself, **how** are you going to free memory ? By using a cleanup function (`foo_destroy`), right ? And the user is supposed to pass this pointer to the cleanup function.

So consider this: if the user is clueless enough to assign an integer to it, **why wouldn't she be clueless enough to forget to cleanup** ?

#### EDIT

Stéphane Gimenez commented *typedef struct foo foo_t is what the OP want*. I would like to underline [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type):

> The only thing that the client can do with an object of such a type is
> to take its address, to produce an opaque pointer.

Comment: You don't understand what is an opaque variable. `typedef struct foo foo_t` **is** what the OP want, preventing assignments too!

Comment: Btw, I already wondered about this myself. I came to the conclusion that C was not smart enough to let you define abstract types like in ML and other languages.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Thank you for commenting :-) Keep this in mind: he tagged **"opaque-pointers"** and he used the term "pointer" in his question.

Comment: Ok :-) Well the tag is still kind of "related". In his example, the actual content is a pointer, but the point is to hide this to the user.

Comment: About the edit: of course the **other thing** you can do with them is to pass them as arguments to functions defined in foo.cpp (which have access to the full data type).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. What I actually want is `typedef struct foo *foo_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this wrongly. How would you initiate a local foo_t variable? If you type

```
void bar(void)
{
  foo_t var;
}
```

then var will contain garbage. The only way to make it clean is to type

```
void bar(void)
{
  foo_t var = NULL;
}
```

or `0` if you wish, but that should emit a warning. The code in your question is thereby not safe, it might crash.

What you can do is to add the nonnull attribute to foo_tile, i.e.:

```
void foo_tile( foo_t t ) __attribute__((nonnull(1)));
```

That will prevent `foo_tile(NULL);` and in some compilers even

```
foo_t var = NULL;
foo_tile(var);
```

though it'll likely just make it a warning, not a hard error.